# How do I design a window similar to VS2015's Tools->Options window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

UPDATE: The problem I am currently having is that I have two different types of items in my tree view. Items that are explicitly created and those creates from the ItemsSource property. The SelectedItem property of the explicitly created TreeViewItems is a TreeViewItem, the SelectedItem of a ItemsSource created item is an instance of the object.

I'm trying to design a window similar to VS2015's Tools->Options window, where I have a TreeView on the left and a ContentPresenter (or some other control?) on the right so that I can bind the ContentPresenter's DataContext to the TreeView's SelectedValue, then the ContentPresenter can somehow select it's content based on the DataContext. I've tried all sorts of approaches, but can't get it right.

The DataContext on my window is an instance of this object

```
public class Settings
{
   public GeneralSettings General { get; } = new GeneralSettings();
   public ObservableCollection<Configuration> Configurations = new ObservableCollection<Configuration>();
   public OtherSettings Other { get; } = new OtherSettings();

   public class GeneralSettings
   {
   }
   public class Configuration
   {
      public string Name { get; } = string.Empty;
   }
   public class OtherSettings
   {
   }
}
```

I want the treeview to look like this

General
- Configutations
|- Configuration1
|- Configuration2
|- ...
|- ConfigurationN
- Other

So I tried this XAML:

```
     <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem Header="General"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Configurations" ItemsSource="{Binding Configurations}"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Other"/>
     </TreeView>
```

But I'm not sure how to bind the root TreeViewItems to their appropriate properties.

Am I going about this all wrong? Any suggestions?